# Algebraic Properties of the Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-writing

Prove that

$$\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}} \leq \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\space dx \space \leq \frac{1}{3}$$

Use: If $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are integrable on $[a, b]$ and $f_1\leq f_2$ then 
$$\int_a^b f_1(x)dx \leq  \int_a^b  f_2(x)dx$$
with a smart choice of functions.

Comment: I can't seem to fix the bounds!  0 to 1.

Comment: @Jewelss I formatted your question with LaTex. Now, what have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you!  I fixed it to what it should exactly be!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I'm not sure how that explains what effort you have made in proving this inequality

Comment: @graydad, it looks like you had a $10x^2$ in the numerator of the integrand, instead of just $x^2$.  But I agree, the OP should edit the question to include a description of what he or she has tried.

Comment: @BarryCipra thank you for that catch!

Comment: So, I am trying to figure out how to use the theorem (Use:) to prove that is true.  I am having trouble finding where to start.

Comment: So, the proof to the Thm.:

We know that inf(f_1) ≤ inf(f_2) and m_i(f_1) ≤ m_i(f_2)

L(P,f_1) ≤ L(P,f_2) for all partitions P
then

supL(P,f_1) ≤ supL(P,f_2) and by definition of integrability, that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $\sqrt{2} \geq \sqrt{1+x^2} \geq 1$

Comment: I don't think that the integral would change.